# Cant trigger action from option select

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have the following in my template:

```
<select>
  {{#each sortedManufacturers key="id" as |manufacturer|}}
    <optgroup label="{{manufacturer.name}}">
      {{#each manufacturer.cars key="id" as |car|}}
        <option {{action "carSelected" car}} value="{{car.model}}">{{car.model}}</option>
      {{/each}}
    </optgroup>
  {{/each}}
</select>
```

In the controller, I have:

```
actions: {
  carSelected(car) {
    console.log(car);
  }
}
```

When the option is selected from the `select`. It doesn't seem to trigger the `carSelected` action.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ember > 1.13 you can do the following:

```
<select onchange={{action "carSelected" value="target.value"}}>
   <!-- ... -->
</select>
```

With component JS:

```
export default Component.extend({
  actions: {
    carSelected(car) {
      // ..
    }
  }
});
```

Or you can use the unquoted “closure action” form:

```
<select onchange={{action carSelected value="target.value"}}>
   <!-- ... -->
</select>
```

With component JS:

```
export default Component.extend({
  carSelected(car) {
    // ..
  }
});
```

See the [improved actions RFC](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/blob/master/text/0050-improved-actions.md) for more on all this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know why click event is not binded to option this way. I beleive it's better to use `change` event on select instead.

```
<select {{action 'carSelected' on='change'}}> ... </select>
```

Here is implementation details: http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_ember-select

Comment: How do you access the `option`, that was selected, in the `carSelected` action?

Comment: You could look at completed code example under link